# With Solr, Do I Need A SQL db as well?

Tags: mysql, database, solr

I'm thinking about using solr to implement spatial and text indexing. At the moment, I have entries going in to a MYSQL database as well as solr. When solr starts, it reads all the data from MYSQL. As new entries come in, my web servers write them to MYSQL and, at the same time, adds documents to solr. More and more, it seems that my MYSQL implementation is just becoming a write-only persisten store (more or less, a backup for the data in solr) - all of the reading of entries are done via solr queries. Really the only data being read from MYSQL is user info, which doesn't need to be indexed/searched.

A few questions:

- Do I really need the MYSQL implementation or could I simply store all of my data in solr?
- If solr only, what are the risks associated with this solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost always, the answer is yes.  It needn't be a database necessarily, but you should retain  the original data somewhere outside of Solr in the event you alter how you index the data in Solr.  Unlike most databases, which Solr is not, Solr can't simple re-index itself.  You could hypothetically configure your schema so that all your original data is marked as "stored" and then perhaps to a CSV dump and re-index that way, but I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Shameless plug: For any information on using Solr, I recommend [my book](http://www.packtpub.com/apache-solr-3-enterprise-search-server/book).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a separate repository. MySQL is one choice. Some people use the filesystem.

You often want a different schema for searching than for storing. That is easy to do with a separate repository.

When you change the Solr schema, you need to reload the content. Unloading all the content from Solr can be slow. If it is already in a separate repository, then you don't need to dump it from Solr, you can overwrite what is there.

In general, making Solr be both a search engine and a repository really reduces your flexibility and options for making search the best it can be.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't have to be a relational database at all. The choice should depend primarily on your data structure and your scaling requirements. There are loads of new NoSQL databases that handle various data architectures, based on distributed: document, column, hash-map, graph, ...